# Groupby error using IEnumerable and List in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing an api controller and need to return list that grouped by product type. I am confused with using IEnumerable vs List. The groupby asks for IEnumerable. Currently I am getting syntactical error at following line in the controller method.

```
missingProducts = missingProducts.GroupBy(a => a.ProductType);

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Manager.WebUI.ViewModels.Allocations.MissingProductsViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Manager.WebUI.ViewModels.Allocations.MissingProductsViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Should I be returning IEnumerable from the method in ApiController base and then doing a ToList() in controller method or  returning a list from ApiController base and then converting the return type to IEnumerable from controller method.

Models

```
public class MISSING_PRODUCT 
{
    public int PRODUCT_ID { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_TYPE { get; set; }
}

public class MissingProductsViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

API Controller base

```
public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
    public List<MISSING_PRODUCT> GetMissingProducts()
    {
       var missingProduct =  
                IoC.Resolve<IPackageService>()
                    .PackageGetList<FN_MISSING_PRODUCTS, MISSING_PRODUCT>(new FN_MISSING_PRODUCTS());
        return missingProduct;
    }
 }
```

Controller method

```
public class AllocationsController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Allocations/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Details(int id, DateTime date)
    {
        var viewModel = GetAllocationsViewModel(id, date);
        if (viewModel == null) return NotFound(); 
        return Ok(viewModel);
    }

    private AllocationsViewModel GetAllocationsViewModel(int id, DateTime date)
    {
        var ms = GetStrategy(id);
        DateTime d = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        if (ms.FIRM_ID != null)
        {
            var missingProducts = Mapper.Map<List<MISSING_PRODUCT>, List<MissingProductsViewModel>>(GetMissingProducts());
            missingProducts = missingProducts.GroupBy(a => a.ProductType);
            var vm = new AllocationsViewModel
            {
                MissingProducts = missingProducts
            };

            return vm;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `missingProducts` will be of type `List<MissingProductsViewModel>` after the `Mapper.Map()` call. However, `GroupBy` will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MissingProductsViewModel>>`.

```
var missingProducts = Mapper.Map<List<MISSING_PRODUCT>, List<MissingProductsViewModel>>(GetMissingProducts());
missingProducts = missingProducts.GroupBy(a => a.ProductType);
```

Change the second line above to this:

```
missingProducts = missingProducts.GroupBy(a => a.ProductType).Select(b => b.ElementAt(0)).ToList();
```

And you may need to do some null checking.

**Edit after Tom's comment**

Below line should give you the missing products by product name:

```
missingProducts = missingProducts.GroupBy(a => a.ProductType).Where(b => b.Key == "PRODUCT_TYPE").SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
```

In that case you do not need the group by, and above line can be simplified to:

```
missingProducts = missingProducts.Where(a => a.ProductType == "PRODUCT_TYPE").ToList();
```

And do not forget to update the hardcoded "PRODUCT_TYPE" string.

Comment: The error has gone but its only returning only first array element for a product type. I need all the array elements for that product type. I think Select(b => b.ElementAt(0)) is the culprit